# Can't find module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, anaconda

I'm trying to do a linear regression using `scipy.stats.linregress()`. However when I run my script, i get the error message

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'stats'*
```

I'm using the Anaconda python 2.7 distribution which in its documentation says to have the module installed. [Anaconda documentation](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs.html)

In the python interactive interpreter, I can import the scipy module, but can't find stats. When I look up its `__version__` it says `0.14`, which should have the stats module..

I really can't guess why the stats is unavailable..

Comment: Can you post the program code you're using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'stats'
```

Means what it says. There is no attribute named `stats` in the `scipy` module.

Not because no such thing exists on disk, but because no such thing has been imported—because you never even tried to import it.

`scipy` is a package. As [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) explains, importing a package doesn't import all of its submodules.

*Some* packages have a `__init.py__` that automatically imports some or all packages.* But that would be a bad idea for `scipy`, because there are a ton of them, so it would take some time to import all of them, and usually you only need one or two in a given project.

So, you just need to do this:

```
import scipy.stats
```

---

<sub>* There are also some cases like `os` which fake being packages but aren't, so you can use `os.path` without importing it, or cases like `pyobjc` that create special placeholder objects for their modules that automatically import the real modules when first accessed.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error when I import `scipy` instead of `scipy.stats`. Have you tried

```
import scipy.stats
scipy.stats.linregress()
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer, just a suggestion for debugging.

Comment: Depends on if whether it fixes the problem I assume.

Comment: I agree. Most possibly the problem is only `import scipy` is used in the code. `stats` is not automatically imported if only using `import scipy`, and this can be confirmed by looking at the file `site-packages/scipy/__init__.py`. `stats` is a submodule that needs to be explicitly imported using `import scipy.stats`